# Compiling a 6GB site

Tags: asp.net, compiler-construction, compilation, umbraco, filesize

This morning I moved a .NET website from our local server to live (not pre-complied). When I go to the url the sites hosted on the browser starts loading the site and has been doing this for the last hour. I presumed it is compiling the site and its just taking a while because of the size of the site. 
Is there any way to check if this is definitely the case and there's nothing else happening?

Comment: How long does it take to compile on a dev box, and why can't you precompile it?

Comment: Its got a lot of hi-res images of products and press office imagery. It cant be pre-compiled because the cms it uses wont allow it.

Comment: What's the size without the images? What CMS are you using? You really need to provide as much detail as possible if you want a coherent answer.

Comment: Its using Umbraco. Without the images its probably about 100mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Put your images in a spearate folder, not in your virtual directory for the application.

@ ck. You obviously haven't used Umbraco before because Umbraco cannot be hosted in a virtual directory.

Umbraco bin zip comes with the site precompiled. I am assuming the reason your site is compiling is because you have ascx usercontrols with ascx.cs files. Maybe some App_Code .cs files.

Put those in another Web Application project. Compile it, and just move the .dll and .ascx files over to the appropriate directories.

Comment: well i only have 9 .cs files in the project. 8 of the ascx code-behinds not much to compile. Certainly shouldnt have taken 6-7 hrs to do. Ill be doing some more work on this site soon so ill give this a go.

Answer (score 0):

Put your images in a spearate folder, not in your virtual directory for the application.

I.e.

```
 Default Web Site
 - Picture folder (5.8GB)
 - Application virtual directory (small application)
```

Comment: The images are using directories created by the cms its gonna be a hell of a lot of hacking around to change that. I dont have the time really to it. Reducing the size of the site isnt the problem to be honest. I dont mind it compiling on the server i just want to make sure that its definitely doing this.

Comment: After looking at this a bit more your idea might just work. In theory all references to the media folder where the directories created by the cms are held are in the db somewhere(hopefully all in one column).